# Query By Last Month, Last Week, Yesterday, And So On

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

I have `orders` table, which contains `orderID` & `order_date`.

I'm trying to query the data by last week, last month, or even by yesterday, however I can't figure out how to subtract time from current time

My `order_date` field is of `TIMESTAMP` type, any idea, any help, would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DATE_SUB:

```
... WHERE order_date > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
```

for taking last month,

```
... WHERE order_date > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK )
```

for getting last week,

```
... WHERE order_date > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY )
```

for getting today and

```
... WHERE order_date BETWEEN ( DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY ), DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY ) )
```

for getting previous day.

Is it what you asked for?

Comment: Exactly, these examples are exactly what I've asked for, thanks a lot, I'd vote your answer up, if I had privileges, thanks again

Comment: can I contact u on private? how? :D

Answer (score 3):

Use mysql `date_sub` function

- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_sub.asp
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: looks greeeeeeat, but would you show me an example of selecting all in an specific interval?

Comment: thnx go to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html there is so many example and please do some google you will find lots of them gud luck

Answer (score 1):

The clue here is DATEDIFF and HAVING.

For last 30 days try something like this (from memory):

```
SELECT orderID, DATEDIFF(order_date, NOW()) AS days FROM table HAVING days <= 30
```